# CSS show div on hover

Tags: html, hover

This is my CSS

```
.header_under{
    display: none;
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    float: left;
    background: red
}
.show:hover ~ .header_under{
    display: block;
}
```

So what I want is the "header_under" to appear on the website on hover. But it seems not to work

HTML:

```
<li class="show"><a href='#'><span>Games4u</span></a></li>
```

And

```
<div class="bildspel">
    <div id="header_under"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `~` is sibling selector, but both elements aren't siblings... Show complete HTML markup to show us relationship between these elements.

Comment: Okey. Well they're not siblings. How can I manage to get this done?

Comment: CSS can target only (next) siblings and children. In other cases you need JS, or... show HTML markup you have, maybe we can find any solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your HTML needs to be structured to match the CSS and it will work.

The tilde (~) operator requires a sibling connection with the target:

```css
#header_under{
    display: none;
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    background: red
}
.show:hover ~ #header_under{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="show">
        <a href='#'><span>Games4u</span></a>
    </li>
    <div id="header_under">dasasdadssad</div>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yeah that snippet is not exactly pretty or valid, but it demonstrates the point. ALSO OP: Note that you mixed header_under class and ID notations,  they need to be correct too.

Comment: You prepare nice markup, but both elements aren't siblings.

Comment: @panther that is my whole point. You can't do this without them .show and .header_under being siblings.  Can you not edit your HTML? You never showed us what is your complete hierarchy and you never said you can't change it. Personally I think this is  not a great method for hovering content to be honest.